# Is Just-in-time (JIT) VM access under Fortigate Firewall is available in Azure

Tags: azure-keyvault, fortigate

I was going through this article : [Just-in-time (JIT) VM access for Azure Firewall is now generally available](http://Just-in-time%20(JIT)%20VM%20access%20for%20Azure%20Firewall%20is%20now%20generally%20available) and [Understanding just-in-time (JIT) VM access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/defender-for-cloud/just-in-time-access-overview)

My questions are :

Is Just-in-time (JIT) VM access using Key Vault for Fortigate Firewall is available in Azure? - Nothing found from  search. If its available, how to implement that? So that, users can access VMs behind the firewall.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not available for FortiGate firewall.

You can find the available options here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/security-center/just-in-time-access-usage?tabs=jit-config-asc%2Cjit-request-asc

Comment: Please avoid posting link-only answers. Also, the question is off-topic as written: there is nothing programming-related; just a request for information/documentation. At best, that link you shared could be a comment.

Comment: @jayakrishnaGunnam-MT - Any article / blog says that its not available ?